# Python problem with contract given (no if statements or loops)

Tags: python, variables

```
def mystery3(salary: int) -> int:
    '''return the income tax for salary by adhering to the following rules:
    Taxable Income               Rate(%)
    First $20000 CAD            0
    The remaining CAD           30
    >>> mystery3(20000)
    0
    >>> mystery3(40000)
    6000.0
    >>> mystery3(45000)
    7500.0
    >>> mystery3(18000)
    0
    '''
    taxable_income=salary-20000
    income_tax= taxable_income*0.3
    return income_tax

print(mystery3(45000))
```

^This is what I've tried so far.

This would be a really easy problem except I'm supposed to code this **without if, elif, else statements or loops.** Basically this program doesn't work for values below 20000 because it's supposed to give 0. however I'm not sure how to code a program that will give me 0 as an output for a salary below 20000. It's supposed to be super basic I just can't seem to get it.

Comment: You are probably supposed to use [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#max).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
taxable_income=salary-20000
taxable_income=max(0, taxable_income)
```

Should do it